# How can I get the view that current view is transmiited from that

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uiwindow

I use below code to transmit from my mainViewController to another `UIViewController`:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:otherUiViewController];
UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
[UIView transitionFromView:window.rootViewController.view
                    toView:navigationController.view
                  duration:1.2f
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                completion:^(BOOL finished){
                    window.rootViewController = navigationController;
                }];
```

at `otherUIViewController` the main subject is that users enter some input and submit that( but they may need some navigation to other pages too, it is why I use `UINavigationController` for showing the `otherUIViewController`) when they submit the input I want to transmit them back to my `mainViewController` (the `UIViewController` that user is transmitted from it)

The question is that what is the best way to transmit back the user? Is there a way that I get the orginal `mainViewController` that showed this `UIViewController` (otherViewController)  and transmit back that or I should create a new instance of my `mainViewController` and use above code again for transmission?

**EDIT**
A very important point that I forget to say is that I want that user can not back to the mainViewController till they submit the input

Comment: Changing the `rootViewController` is rarely a good idea. It tends to have unwanted side effects. Consider making your navigation controller the `rootViewController` and make your main view controller its `topViewController`. Now you can push any view controllers you need to show onto the navigation stack and pop back to the top view controller at any point.

Comment: I want that user can not back to my mainViewController till it submit the input

Comment: You can do that with a navigation controller as the `rootViewController`. Just don't enable the back button until the user has entered enough data. Alternatively, use `presentViewController:animated:completion` to present the navigation controller modally on top of the `rootViewController`.

Comment: @LevLandau if you want, you can create an answer an I will accept it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two good options for achieving this:

Have a `navigationController` as the `rootViewController` and your current main view controller as its `topViewController`. Push the view controller you need the user to enter data into. Make sure to keep the back button disabled until all data has been entered.

The other option is to keep the main view controller as the `rootViewController` and use `presentViewController:animated:completion: to present the navigation controller modally from it.

It should be noted that replacing the `rootViewController` is rarely a good idea as it has unwanted side effects.

Good Coding!